# spring cloud how to set encrypt.key property

Tags: spring, encryption, cloud

I work with spring cloud and I want to set encrypt.key property.

My application has bootstrap.yml but I don't have bootstrap.properties.

How can I set encrypt.key?

I get
{
    "description": "The encryption algorithm is not strong enough",
    "status": "INVALID"
}

when I executed localhost:8888/encrypt

Answer (score 1):

Simply put `encrypt.key=keyName` in you `bootstrap.yml` or `bootstrap.properties` file to avoid the error

```
{"description": "The encryption algorithm is not strong enough", "status": "INVALID" }
```

while running config server locally.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone could find useful.
If you're using Spring Boot 3 and you have dependency from spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap, remove it. It worked for me.
Actually as I know, bootstrap properties yaml (bootstrap.yml) are deprecated for Spring Boot 3.
So, just set `encrypt.key` property in application.yml.